# C++ AMP, for loops to parallel_for_each loop

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-amp

I'm converting an algorithm to make use of the massive acceleration that C++ AMP provides. The stage I'm at is putting the for loops into the known parallel_for_each loop.

Normally this should be a straightforward task to do but it appears more complex then I first thought. It's a nested loop which I increment using steps of 4 per iterations:

```
for(int j = 0; j < height; j += 4, data += width * 4 * 4)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i += 4)
    {
```

The trouble I'm having is the use of the index. I can't seem to find a way to properly fit this into the parallel_for_each loop. Using an index of rank 2 is the way to go but manipulating it via branching will do harm to the performance gain.

I found a similar post: [Controlling the index variables in C++ AMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853894/controlling-the-index-variables-in-c-amp). It also deals about index manipulation but the increment aspect doesn't cover my issue.

With kind regards,

Forcecast

Comment: Perhaps you could use [tiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873135%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to partition your data into 4x4 tiles.

Comment: +1 for tiles. AMP's parallel_for_each is really only that: It iterates over each element in a range. No skipping, no jumping ahead. Whenever you need more than that, you'll probably want to use a `tiled_extent`.

Comment: Thank you both for your reply. It makes sense to use tiles for such case indeed when I take a closer look at it. I just wanted to make sure I didn't drop any obvious other reasons I might have missed. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: After more R&D concerning tile usage, using 4x4 tiles can lead to performance loss -> [warp or wavefront of GPU threads](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/03/26/warp-or-wavefront-of-gpu-threads.aspx). It comes down to this: "In modern GPUs, the size of a warp/wavefront is normally 32 or 64. With 4 x 4 tile, each tile will only have one un-filled warp/wavefront, this leads to under-utilization of computation resources."

Answer (score 0):

You should think of tiles as a mechanism for partitioning work across the GPU not as an indexing mechanism. As you found limiting yourself to a 4x4 tile is likely to lead you into a performance bottleneck.

Can't you just do the following:

```
auto compute_domain = concurrency::extent<2>(height / 4, width / 4);

parallel_for_each(accl_view, compute_domain, [=](index<2> idx) restrict(amp)
{
    int j = idx[0] * 4;
    int i = idx[1] * 4;

    // Your algorithm here...
}
```